# Lifetime of temporaries in initializer_lists nested in function calls

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the lifetime of a temporary in something like `func({someString,
std::string("foo")})`? I ask because the `initializer_list` in question is
actually of type `initializer_list<Foo>` (not `initializer_list<string>`), and
the ctor of Foo stores the address of its argument as a pointer. Will such
temporaries be destructed after the `initializer_list` is created, but before
the function call? Or will the temporaries always live for the duration of the
function call?

Some sample code is provided below, along with the output produced by running
the code with clang++ 8.0.0. The temporaries appears to live for the duration
of the function call on my particular system, but is this behavior standard,
and will it be consistent across different compilers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    const string* x;

    Foo(const string& str) : x(&str) {
        printf("Foo::Foo()\n");
    }

    ~Foo() {
        printf("Foo::~Foo()\n");
    }
};

void
funcA(initializer_list<Foo> args)
{
    (void)args;
    printf("funcA()\n");
}

void
funcB(vector<Foo> args)
{
    (void)args;
    printf("funcB()\n");
}

void
funcC(const vector<Foo>& args)
{
    (void)args;
    printf("funcC()\n");
}

int
main()
{
    string a;

    printf("=========\n");
    funcA({a, string("foo")});
    printf("=========\n");
    funcB({a, string("bar")});
    printf("=========\n");
    funcC({a, string("baz")});
    printf("=========\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
=========
Foo::Foo()
Foo::Foo()
funcA()
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
=========
Foo::Foo()
Foo::Foo()
funcB()
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
=========
Foo::Foo()
Foo::Foo()
funcC()
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
Foo::~Foo()
=========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary objects have a lifetime up to the end of the statement. They will be available for any function call in this statement but not beyond. So, you may pass references and use the temporary objects. Their addresses should only not be stored away for a later references.

Comment: Emphasise the last paragraph.  If the functions store the arguments in an object for later use, any subsequent use of the references (or dereferencing pointers in this case) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: "End of statement" isn't quite right. For example, `if (x == f()) { /* ... */ }`, a temporary object that results from `f()` is destroyed before the compound-statement of the `if` statement. [Demo](https://ideone.com/cTF1Jx).

Comment: @Peter The pointers are only used within the function call itself. The reason I'm doing things this way is that there's no way to avoid copying when passing objects to functions via braced initializer_list notation. You can't have std::vector<T&>, and std::vector<T*> forbids using temporaries like func({T(), T(), ...}). This weird hack is the only workaround. You pass a temporary and then store a pointer to it... and, damn it, I just realized that move semantics obviate all of theses issues. FML.

Comment: Though actually, even if I relied on move semantics here to efficiently pass around temporaries in a call like func({T(), T(), ...}), then there would still be copying involved in something like func({existingValueA, existingValueB, ...}). For that you still need my hack, I think. It's not the point of this post really, but if anybody has other ideas then do tell!